# Rule to notify admin by email whenever anyone updates a field in a user profile

Tags: 8, rules

I have allowed a certain 'role' to change/edit fields in 'registered' users' fields. I want to receive an email in the admin's inbox detailing these changes using Rules.

I tried and failed!

Any help to achieve this?

i.e.

```
Subject: [user, who changed the field in a registered user's profile] changed [user, whose profile settings have been changed] profile
Body: [changed by]
[user whose profile was changed]
[value of changed filed in profile]
[value changed at]
```

Comment: Have you made a new account and received an e-mail? Just want to check that your e-mailing system works and that Rules is indeed the where the issue is at.

Answer (score -2):

I am giving you the alternate idea instead of using rules,you can use hook_form_alter.

```
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
 function getCurrentUserRecord()
 {
  $myArray = []; 
  $x = db_select('users_field_data','cw')
    ->fields('cw',['name','pass','mail'])
    ->execute()->fetchAll();

  foreach($x as $v){
    $myArray = $v;  
  }
  return $myArray;
  }

function nestle_viewalter_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

      if($form_id == "user_form")
       {

            foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
  $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'nestle_viewalter_form_submit';
   }
   }
   }

   }
function nestle_viewalter_form_submit(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
$records = getCurrentUserRecord();

$field=$form_state->getValues();
$mail = $field[mail];
$name = $field[name];

if($records->name == $name || $records->mail == $mail)  {
    drupal_set_message(t("No changes so far"), 'error');
}
  else{

    $mailManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail');
    $module = 'nestle_viewalter';
    $key = 'update_profile';
    $to = 'vikram@sparxitsolutions.com';
    $send = true;
    $result = $mailManager->mail($module, $key, $to,NULL, $send);

    if ($result['result'] !== true) {
        drupal_set_message(t('There was a problem sending your message and it was not sent.'), 'error');
    }
    else {
        drupal_set_message(t('Your message has been sent.'));
    }

    drupal_set_message(t("Send mail"), 'status');
}
}

  function nestle_viewalter_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
 switch ($key) {
 case 'update_profile':
 $message['from'] = \Drupal::currentUser()->getEmail();
 $message['subject'] = t('Profile updated');
 $message['body'][] = 'this is a test mail from the current user as i have updated my profile.';
 break;
 }
 }
```

Comment: That was sweet. That makes me to ask you to send me a link which explains IN DETAIL the process of attaching this hook to drupal 8 through module. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Vikram can you help me to make a module named inform_user_changes